# my laravel sub-domain urls does not work except homepage

Tags: web-hosting, php, subdomain, shared-hosting, laravel

I am new to hosting web apps online. I wanted to host an app in my subdomain eg `departmennt1.example.com`. I added the subdomain in cPanel. Located its directory in file manager. It happens that the subdmain is also a folder in the root directory. I upload the locally working site in the subdomain folder. After setting up my database on the `.env` folder. I also ensure that my public folder files were inside the subdomain folder. I ensure that the app and the `autoload.php` in `index.php` file in the subdomain folder is pointing correctly to the vendor and boostrap folder.

After that, I tried loading the subdomain address in the browser, but only the index page ie.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

any other URL will return like login will show

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried it on another hosting company where the subdomain by default resides in the `public_html` directory and everything worked out fine.

How can I host at the first hosting company?

Comment: If you only have an index.html file in the directory does it display it?  If not then there is something wrong with the way the subdomain is pointing to the document root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the whole problem by changing my **.htaccess** file from

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I dont know what the code above does. I'll love it to get explation for the greater good of all

Comment: This code basically sends all "virtual URL" requests to `index.php` (the Laravel front-controller) for Laravel to then lookup the route and build the page. You _must_ have had something similar when you tried this at the other host that worked, otherwise you would have had 404s for all but the home page as well. (Requesting the root directory would call `index.php` by default - so these directives are not required for the home page.) If you _removed_ the `AddHandler` directive then you might find you are now running a different version of PHP.

Comment: The code was actually set automatically from the second host. I spotted the difference and tried to gave it a trial. And luckily it worked. Both the two hosting companies had diffrent directory for the subdomain file. The one i had problem with had it subdomain folder in the root directory, with the second had the subomain folder in public_html directory